# I can't use get_foo_display in django template

Tags: django

I use 'choice set' in my model but I can't show their labels in template

In model:

```
class Malpractice_Detail(models.Model):
    
    DayTime_Choice={
        ('morning','صبح'),
        ('noon','ظهر'),
        ('night','شب'),
    }
    
    Damage_Choice={
        ('1','عدم آسیب'),
        ('2','آسیب به بیمار'),   
        ('3','آسیب به پرسنل'),
        ('4','آسیب به تجهیزات پزشکی'),
    }
    
    malperactice_choice={
        ('1','خطاهای دارویی'),
        ('2','خطاهای احیاء قلبی-ریوی'),
        ('3','خطادرتزریقات وخونگیری'),
        ('4','خطادر ثبت اطلاعات وثبت پرونده'),
        ('5','خطاهای مراقبتی وبالینی'),
        ('6','اشتباهات پاراکلینیکی'),
        ('7','اشتباهات جراحی'),
        ('8','خطاهای تشخیصی پزشک'),
        ('9','اشتباهات تجهیزاتی'),
        ('10','اشتباهات مدیریتی')
    }
    hospital=models.ForeignKey('Accounting.hospital', verbose_name='بیمارستان',null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="نام شخصی که خطا از او سرزده",null=True, blank=True)
    unit=models.ForeignKey('Accounting.unit', verbose_name='بخش',null=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    time=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=DayTime_Choice,null=False,blank=False,verbose_name='زمان وقوع')
    type=models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=malperactice_choice,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name="نوع خطا")
    date=models.DateField("تاریخ رخداد خطا", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    role=models.ForeignKey('role', verbose_name='سمت خطاکار',null=False,blank=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    damage=models.CharField(max_length=1,verbose_name='آسیب وارد شده',choices=Damage_Choice,default=1,null=False,blank=False)
    st_happened=models.TextField(max_length=1000,verbose_name='شرح خطای رخ داده',null=False,blank=False)
    decisions=models.TextField(max_length=1000,verbose_name='تصمیمات اتخاذ شده',null=True,blank=True)
    cause_of_accident=models.TextField(max_length=1000,verbose_name='دلیل رخداد خطا',null=True,blank=True)
    solution=models.TextField(max_length=1000,verbose_name='پیشنهاد و راهکار',null=True,blank=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    reporting_datetime=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_seen=models.BooleanField(verbose_name='دیده شده',default=False,null=True,blank=True)
    has_followup=models.BooleanField(verbose_name='شرح پیگیری دارد',default=False,null=True,blank=True)
    has_feedback=models.BooleanField(verbose_name='شرح بازخورد دارد',default=False,null=True,blank=True)
    
    
    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.st_happened)
    class Meta:
        ordering=['-reporting_datetime']
```

In View:

```
def Index(request):
    form=Malpractice_Detail.objects.select_related('Hospital','Unit','Role').filter(user=request.user).values('unit__name','date','role__Name','damage','st_happened','is_seen','has_followup','has_feedback')
    
    return render(request,"malpractice/index.html",{'form':form})
```

In template: show damage code but not show damage label

```
{% for item in form  %}
<td>{{item.date|to_jalali:'%Y/%m/%d'}}</td>
<td>{{item.damage}}</td>## This show number of choice
<td>{{item.get_damage_display}}</td> ##Not show label
<td>{{item.st_happened}}</td>
```

I reed many post about this and try solutions but don't work for me
please help me for solve this problem

Comment: Don't use `.values()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please [*don't* use `.values(…)` <sup>[django-antipaterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html): [**`.values(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values) provides dictionaries, and other native types, it is a [*primitive obsession* antipattern <sup>[refactoring.guru]</sup>](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession) and will for example for `ForeignKey`s return their primary key, not the corresponding model item.

Just let Django wrap these in `Malpractice` objects, so that it ships with all the logic attached to it:

```
def Index(request):
    form = Malpractice_Detail.objects.select_related(
        'Hospital', 'Unit', 'Role'
    ).filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'malpractice/index.html', {'form': form})
```

You access the `.name` of the `.unit` then with:

```
{{ item.unit.name }}
```

---

> **Note**: It might be better to use the [**`@login_required`** decorator
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)
> as a decorator, and thus wrap the function in it like:
>
> ```
> from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
>
> @login_required
> def Index(request):
>     # …
> ```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `Hospital` instead of <s>`hospital`</s>.